# How to show component outlines and designators in Altium PCB view

Tags: altium

I am routing a PCB in Altium 21.

I cannot seem to figure out how to show component outlines and designators on the PCB.

As of now components only show the pads.

How do I enable the component outline and designators in the 2D PCB view?

Comment: Is it in single-layer mode? Shift-S one or more times.

Comment: If cycling through Shift-S does not show the other layers, check that those other layers are visible within the Layers section of the View Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Hit Shift-S to make sure you are not in single layer mode. Then hit L and select the layers you want to see. (another way to get to it is through design->boardlayers and colors)

While in this mode you can choose standard views, create your own (with your own colors) or select which layers are visible.